# Buildup of white powder where metal has been touching a salt stone

Tags: metal, salt

The other day, I opened a box for my cellar I use to store random junk and found this:

[image: Metal jewelry sitting on top of a pink, semi-transparent salt stone. The jewelry is composed of a wire shaped into a ring and metal beads in different round and pointed shapes. White, green-tinted powder has formed around the parts of the jewelry touching the salt stone.]

The pink stone is a salt stone from a pet store. I assume it's NaCl with impurities. The ring is some metal jewelery I found on the ground. Maybe copper or some alloy? Some white build-up has appeared where the metal thing is touching the salt stone.

The metal thing seems to be fused to the stone (I didn't pull too hard), but some of the build-up fell into the container as white power:

[image: Random, small memorabilia sitting at the bottom of a wooden box with white powder strewn across it. Among these is a brass coin whose top has partially turned green.]

Silly me touched the powder to taste it. It tastes like nothing, not salty at all. But it seems the poweder did muck around with a brass (?) coin sitting below it. Especially the bottom, which was sitting against the wooden container and not touching the salt stone above it, was hit hard:

[image: The underside of the same brass coin with most of its surface turned green. Irregular shaped white dots spread across the whole surface.]

There are more of that coin in this continer and they're still as shiny as when I put them into the box.

Here are two additional photos of the thing:

[image: The jewelry and salt stone taken out of the wooden box and put in different lighting conditions.]

[image: Again, the jewelry and salt stone taken out of the wooden box and put in different lighting conditions.]

The box has been sitting in my cellear for about 1.5 years. It shouldn't be above 60% rel. humidity. There's some non-stainless steel stuff and paper in the same box that don't look like they were able to pick up a lot of humidity.

So, can anyone explain what's going on here? What is the white powder composed of?

Comment: This looks like galvanic corrosion between dissimilar metals, mediated by (small amounts of) salt water.  You've basically created a battery.

Comment: maybe salt impurities

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This link https://www.corrosionpedia.com/does-zinc-rust/7/7030 describes, among other air stability properties of zinc, formation conditions of powdery zinc hydroxide. The ring may be copper-zinc alloy. The conditions in Your box match the ones described in the link above: Salinity and the lack of free flowing air.

I am not sure about the black coating on Your coin, but I suspect it contains copper.

If the ring seems to be fused to salt, it definitely is because of changing air humidity over time.

Comment: It looks like maybe the white powder came from specific beads instead of the ring itself. Zinc is a reasonably common material to make beads from.